# struggling with memset

Tags: python, memset

I would like to have a pointer like function. Since I'm allowed to only pass an `int` as an argument and I would like to be able to pass all kind of data to a function. (I can't modify this function it's hardcoded in an SDK)

So I thought to use the id of a variable and then re-assign the value to another value which will be in my function.

I would like to have something like that who is working

```
import ctypes

a = 10
b = 12
print b #here I want 12

ctypes.memset(id(b), a, 8)
print b #here I want 10
```

The possibility to use python type will be great, that way I will be able also to pass a callable object.

Comment: Can you pass `long` as an argument too?

Comment: The documentation say int but I tested with a long it worked.
What will be the benefit to use long instead of int? 
anyway thanks for taking the time to answerd

Comment: You can use lists: `a=[10]; b=[12]; print b[0]; b=a; print b[0]; a[0]=8; print b[0];`

Comment: No I can't since I can't pass a list as an arguments :/
a will be define in other scope/script so I really need a pointer like

Comment: I didn't get it, since the autor said it worked I decided to try it out, but I could not make it work. May someone show with code example how should I use `long`? Also I would like to know how to memset booleans instead of integers. @Philip Tzou

Answer (score -1):

Update:

Since the main thread and background thread are on the same program and sharing memory. You can use a single dictionary to create a container for storing variables and their keys:

```
import random

mystorage = {}


def getint(value):
    while True:
        key = random.randint(0, 0xffffffff)
        if key in mystorage:
            continue
        mystorage[key] = value
        return key


def getvalue(key):
    return mystorage.get(key)
```

You may need to add a write lock when testing if the key conflicted based on your situation. But generally this works fine for multi-thread program.

---

Just an idea to use `int` (actually `long`) type to pass any picklable objects:

```
import codecs
import pickle


def dumps(payload):
    data = pickle.dumps(payload)
    return int(codecs.encode(data, 'hex'), 16)


def loads(intval):
    data = codecs.decode(hex(intval)[2:].encode('ascii'), 'hex')
    return pickle.loads(data)


assert loads(dumps({'foo': 'bar'})) == {'foo': 'bar'}
# no error
```

If you are using Python 3.2+, you can also use `int.from_bytes()` and `int.to_bytes()` to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks that was a nice idea.

But sadly we are sticky to 2.7 python and it seem internally the sdk do a conversion from long to int since I got this error:
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

But was a nice idea !

Comment: @graphos Well if you can call the SDK multiple times, you can split the big number to a few smaller ones. Then it won't give OverflowError. You can even preserve a few sequence bytes to keep those numbers in order if the SDK can't guarantee to run the numbers in order.

Comment: Yeah this can be an idea but it's not clean since the argument passed into this function are in the main thread while our call to the function is on a background thread. Wich will lead to a flood and a latencity of the main thread. But it's a solution that will work. So I gonna go for it if there is no other solution.

Comment: @graphos OK. Also I'm not sure if the sending side and the receiving side of the variable are in a same program (and shared the memory). But generally you may want to try `memcache`: storing your object in `memcache` but passing the unique integer key you created to the SDK. That can even work across multiple machines.

Comment: It will be on the same program.So the memory is shared. It's for that I want to use memset.
And I would like to not use external library since it's a bit boring for customer installation.
Is there a way in python to copy the memory representation of an object and then past to another? The sdk offer a way for storing byte and get an uuid of this byte so I can recover them later.

Anyway thanks for all your research ! :)

Comment: I think this can work. Gonna make some test.

again thanks for your perseverance !

Comment: Yeaaahhh it working fine !! Thanks you alot
is there any reason for doing key = random.randint(0, 0xffffffff) than mannualy assign?
Or is just to prevent multiple background thread to call with the same id and that will lead to a lost of data?

Comment: @graphos The random numbers reduced the chance that keys get conflicted. And since you have multiple background thread, you'd better use [Lock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) around the key-check and value-assign code to make it thread safe. Also don't forget to pop key-value out of the dictionary when you don't need them, or you'll be sooner or later out of memory.

Comment: Yeah the sdk offer threading function. So I will use them for managing the thread it will be more clean to let it do what he want to do than managing thread manually.
And thanks you for all of your litlle tips ! :) Sadly I can't upvote you but again thanks you !

Comment: Since it's not on the same namespace it will not work :/
Is it really impossible to have pointer in python ?

Comment: @graphos Then just use memcache instead of Python dictionary.